# What would be a real-life example of when inserting/deletion is not common, but searching is?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

In Data Structures and Algorithms in Java, the advantages of ordered arrays are stated. One of the advantages, I wish I had some kind of real example for. This is not for homework, but just self-clarification. What are some real cases for when insertion/deletion is not frequent, but searches are frequent? Anything would help even if you can point me in the direction of some github repository. Thank you.

Comment: When you can preload a large amount of seldom changing data. Or, it is historical data. For example, how many new phone calls will you have on your phone bill for last month?

Comment: An English dictionary.  You may want to write a program that looks for words to check for spelling, look up the pronunciation, etc., but your program is not going to be inventing new words or deciding on its own to remove words from the language.  There are tons of examples like that where you're getting data already collected from some other source.  The other source may be doing the insertions and deletions, but at some point it will make it available for other programs to use, and those other programs will be looking up data but not modifying it.

Comment: 1. **ONLINE-LEARNING PORTALS**
One either searches the topic he/she wants to learn OR index for all available topics is provided where one can lookup for required topic.
Also there is least inputs and negligible deletion.
*e.g.: coursera, pluralsight, tutorialspoint*
 2. **ONLINE TICKET BOOKING(BUS/TRAIN)**
Majority of actions on such sites is w.r.t. searching available seats in appropriate bus/train.
Insertion is only when one books the ticket. And deletion is even relatively less as *ticket cancellation* is less as compared to searching and booking the tickets.

Answer (score 7):

An example would be a dictionary.  After it is built, it can be looked up millions of time.  Like your paper dictionary, the words in it better be sorted.

Answer (score 2):

While I like leeyuiwah's answer, a more common domain which you can see in commercial context is a data base of some entity, for example the customers or employees, for which normally you create a view. That's why we index them (make the retrieval faster). Indeed, after inserting some records most of the operations will be retrieval which includes a search (based on complicated conditions or a simple identifier).